# The thread order issue in handler object

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I have a handler object as below, just an example
My question is: if someone calls dataSync.setDataEnabled(true) then call dataSync.getDateEnabled() immediately. Can we make sure set/get still execute in order in dataSync class? Because we use message to write data but read data directly.

Thanks

```
class dataSync extends Handler {
    ...

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        case CMD_SET_DATA_ENABLE_SYN:
        final boolean enabled = ((boolean)msg.arg1) ? true : false;
        setDataEnabledSync(enabled);
        break;  
    }

    public boolean getDateEnabled() {
        sync (mLock) {
            return mDataEnabled;
        }
    }

    void setDataEnabled(boolean enable) {
        Message msg = obtainMessage(CMD_SET_DATA_ENABLE_SYNC);
        msg.arg1 = enable ? 1 : 0;
        sendMessage(msg);
    }

    void setDataEnabledSync(enabled); {
        sync (mLock) {
            mDataEnabled = enabled;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that there is mismatch between the title and the content. Could you please change it?

Comment: Thanks, is this more clear?

Comment: and what "thread order" do you mean?  i don't see any other threat,  just main UI one

Comment: So do you mean even we read directly,  the thread will still run in dataSync main UI thread?  Or read request thread should run in client read thread, because it's called by caller directly? 

Thanks

Comment: Handler != Thread, its handleMessage is called in the same thread it was created (unless you use explicit Looper in the Handler's constructor)

Comment: Thanks, but I still have questions.
If we create dataSync object in another class (ex, class DataManger) in boot time. Afterwards other clients will use same DataManager to set/get data enable, set/get threads is different from dataSync creating thread. Under such scenario, can we still make sure set/get requests able to execute in order in dataSync object?

Comment: sorry i dont understand what you mean...

Comment: The question :
If we create dataSync object in thread(A), and it will stay in a background process(like service .. etc). Afterwards, thread -B in another process  will set/get data enabled by same interface(by the dataSync object created in thread-A). 

If we need Thread - B ==> setDataEnabled(true) then getDataEnabled()

Under such scenario, can we make sure dataSync object exectute command in order, set first and then get.

Or could dataSync object execute get first and then set ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is YES! It could be happen in this scenario.
"dataSync" this handler will queue the message and execute "in order call", BUT another thread will call "getDateEnabled()" immediately.

So when "dataSync" handler queue a lot messages it will go wrong.